# Seleccionar registros únicos con la fecha mas reciente - ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Tengo en Oracle la tabla "usuario" con la siguiente estructura y registros de ejemplo:

```
TIPO_ID NUM_ID  EDAD    FECHA_REPORTE
CC  111111  20  26/09/2014
CC  111111  21  26/09/2015
CC  111111  22  26/09/2016
TI  222222  18  30/05/2011
TI  222222  19  30/05/2012
MS  111111  15  14/12/2017
```

Quiero obtener el listado de usuarios con la combinación TIPO_ID y NUM_ID únicos con la fecha más reciente sin mostrar la fecha mas reciente:

```
TIPO_ID NUM_ID  EDAD    
CC  111111  22  
TI  222222  19
MS  111111  15
```

¿Alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Comment: Evita poner imagenes, pon los datos reales. vos queres el registro que tiene la mayor fecha? lo digo por el campo edad, que tampoco tiene una correlacion con los otros. Es importante que ademas demuestres que intentaste hasta ahora

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias

Comment: Uff! Has cambiado la pregunta como 3 veces XDDDD La respuesta que te di ya no corre Jajaja! (Ahora entiendo por qué @gbianchi encontró mala mi respuesta x_x)

Comment: Si, cambie la pregunta inicial y tuve respuesta inmediata, por tal motivo y considerando que no era lo que necesitaba, modifique el enunciado.

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entiendo, tus campos TIPO_ID y NUM_ID se repiten siempre, o sea, son parte de la PK de la tabla usuarios? Así a primeras, creo que con un GROUP BY te resultaría:

```
SELECT TIPO_ID, NUM_ID, MAX(FEC_REPORTE) AS ULT_FECHA
FROM usuario
GROUP BY TIPO_ID, NUM_ID;
```

EDITADO: Uhm, si además quieres la EDAD en tu tabla resultado, ya no te serviría la consulta anterior (al menos en Oracle ni TSQL resultaría, si mal no recuerdo, porque en Mysql sí). Yo uso esta opción en esos casos:

```
SELECT u.TIPO_ID, u.NUM_ID, u.EDAD, t.ULT_FECHA
FROM
  usuario u INNER JOIN
  (SELECT TIPO_ID, NUM_ID, MAX(FEC_REPORTE) AS ULT_FECHA
   FROM usuario
   GROUP BY TIPO_ID, NUM_ID) t
 ON u.TIPO_ID = t.TIPO_ID AND u.NUM_ID = t.NUM_ID;
```

Comment: voy a intentar con lo que tu propones

Comment: La segundo consulta no va a funcionar, ya que al igualar por tipo_id y num_id va a traer todos los registros que sean iguales, sin importar la fecha. Se debe igualar por fecha tambien, y sacar la fecha del select (como pidio OP)

Comment: @gbianchi Otra opción es que haga una subquery por cada renglón del SELECT, pero como sea, ambas formas serán costosas para el servidor :o En cuanto a que la consulta no funcione, no entiendo por qué lo dices :o El select en el FROM retorna una tabla, a la que aplico el alias "t", y de esa tabla sólo obtengo la ULT_FECHA...

Comment: @quinqui pasate por el [chat] si puedes y te lo explico. Pero si igualas solo por esos campos, vas a volver a traer todos los registros. digamos que tu tabla devuelve CC  111111  22  26/09/2016, pero al igualar solo por los primeros dos, vas a traer los 3 de vuelta (y no solo el que tenia el max) y si trajeras uno solo (cosa que no va a pasar) no puedes asegurar que sea la edad que queres.

Answer (score 0):

Agradezco a todos por las contribuciones, por ello, encontré la siguiente solución (query):

```
SELECT u.TIPO_ID, u.NUM_ID, u.EDAD
FROM
  usuario u INNER JOIN
  (SELECT TIPO_ID, NUM_ID, MAX(FEC_REPORTE) AS ULT_FECHA
   FROM usuario
   GROUP BY TIPO_ID, NUM_ID) t
 ON u.TIPO_ID = t.TIPO_ID AND u.NUM_ID = t.NUM_ID AND u.FEC_REPORTE = t.ULT_FECHA;
```

Answer (score 0):

@ALEXANDER Revisando tu caso he encontrado una posible solución,
si tienes un problema no dudes en comentarlo,Espero te sirva.

```
/*
    CREATE TABLE PRUEBA (TIPO_ID VARCHAR(2),NUM_ID NUMBER(10),EDAD NUMBER(3) ,FECHA_REPORTE DATE);

    INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES('CC' , 111111 , 20 , TO_DATE('26/09/2014'));
    INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES('CC' , 111111 , 21 , TO_DATE('26/09/2015'));
    INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES('CC' , 111111 , 22 , TO_DATE('26/09/2016'));
    INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES('TI' , 222222 , 18 , TO_DATE('30/05/2011'));
    INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES('TI' , 222222 , 19 , TO_DATE('30/05/2012'));
    INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES('MS' , 111111 , 15 , TO_DATE('14/12/2017'));

    COMMIT;

 */
    SELECT TIPO_ID,NUM_ID,EDAD 
    FROM (
            SELECT TIPO_ID,NUM_ID,EDAD,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TIPO_ID,NUM_ID ORDER BY FECHA_REPORTE DESC) ORDEN
            FROM PRUEBA
         ) WHERE ORDEN = 1;
```